# What does the following configuration mean in the context of WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I added a WCF as a service reference to my client app from VS2013 and it generated the following config section in the app.config file.

```
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
```

What does this mean? The security mode is message but there are separate entities inside that for transport and message. I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two primary choices for providing transfer security: either you provide the transfer security on the transport level, or on the message level.

There is a nice article on MSDN discussing this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx).

**Transport Security:**

> When using transport security, the user credentials and claims are
>   passed by using the transport layer. In other words, user credentials
>   are transport-dependent, which allows fewer authentication options
>   compared to message security.

**Message Security:**

> When using message security, the user credentials and claims are
>   encapsulated in every message using the WS-Security specification to
>   secure messages. This option gives the most flexibility from an
>   authentication perspective. You can use any type of security
>   credentials you want, largely independent of transport, as long as
>   both the client and service agree.

**Update per comment**

What it means in the context of the configuration file that you provided:

After setting a `security mode` (in this case `message`), you have the option of setting the client credential type. The client credential type property specifies what type of credential the client must provide to the service for authentication. In this case, if either `transport` or `message` are specified as the `security mode` then they will use `None` as the client credential type which means that the client does not have to present any credential.

Currently, the following line is essentially being ignored as `message` is the specified `security mode`.

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None" />
```

Comment: Yes I do agree with that. But in the context of the config i have mentioned what does it mean is my question.